# What is a proper use for Prop.delay in ScalaCheck

Tags: scala, quickcheck, scalacheck, property-based-testing

Delayed generators could make sense for recursive data structures. I'm wondering in which situation this `Prop.delay` could be helpful. Could you please demonstrate a real life example.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm wondering in which situation this Prop.delay could be helpful.
>   Could you please demonstrate a real life example.

Say you were writing extensions to your property-based test suite in Scalacheck, and wanted the user to build their properties, and your extension expects properties but shouldn't execute them right away.

Actually, Scalacheck uses the `Prop.delay` construct properties internally to allow users to define tests with the `Properties` trait/superclass.

```
class BadExample extends Properties("Bad example") {
  property("divide by 0") = {
    Prop.forAllNoShrink { x: Int =>
      x / 0 == 0 // No!
    }
  }
}
```

This collects the properties so that they can be executed by a test runner (as an app or through sbt)

```
sealed class PropertySpecifier() {
  def update(propName: String, p: => Prop) = {
    props += ((name+"."+propName, Prop.delay(p)))
  }
}

private val props = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(String,Prop)]

lazy val property = new PropertySpecifier()
```